# if different methods have difference 0.5 in third decimal place while finding accuracy then what to conclude?

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, method-comparison

For the comparison of different feature selection methods and evaluating performance metrics. After evaluation when their is only 0.5 difference in third decimal place. Is this difference is compatible?
E.g.       Method1 Method2 Method3
Accuaracy  0.9881  0.9850  0.9801. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try ensembling the three models and check what is the outcome of that. Because ensemble will increase the accuracy and take out the best out of three of these models. Also, there might be a possibility these models are overfitting so try checking it with validation set and if there's no overfitting then pick the highest scoring model and ensemble using that model as the top performer of the ensemble.